# Cannot migrate my java code to Elasticsearch 2.4 (Java API)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, elasticsearch, jackson

I recently migrated to Elasticsearch 2.4 in my Java code. I am using the following external libs in my gradle file:

```
'spring-data-mongodb': 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.6.0.RELEASE',
'spring-data-rest': 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:2.2.0.RELEASE',
'spring-webmvc': 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.7.RELEASE',
'elasticsearch-client': 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:2.4.0',
'spring-context': 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.7.RELEASE',
'jackson': 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.1',
'commons-io': 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4',
'commons-codec': 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.8',
'commons-httpclient': 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6',
'commons-lang': 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2',
'commons-collections': 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0',
'commons-cli': 'commons-cli:commons-cli:1.3',
'commons-csv': 'org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.1',
'joda-time': 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3',
'spring-reactor': 'org.projectreactor.spring:reactor-spring-context:1.1.3.RELEASE',
'json-smart': 'net.minidev:json-smart:1.3.1',
'mongeez': 'org.mongeez:mongeez:0.9.3',
'mongo-driver': 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.12.3',
'akka-actor': 'com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.10:2.3.13',
'scala-library': 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.4
```

I am using mockmvc to test my project. The error is occurring in MockMvc.java class and is the following:

Could not instantiate bean class:

```
[org.springframework.hateoas.hal.Jackson2HalModule$HalLinkListDeserializer]: Constructor threw exception

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ContainerDeserializerBase: method (Ljava/lang/Class;)V not found
```

I think that this is is problem related to Jackson dependencies but I am not sure.

Comment: Why do you think the problem related to jackson dependencies?

Comment: @RomanC because his error is that some compiled code is calling Jackson method that doesn't exist in his given set of dependencies.  Which means it is likely the wrong Jackson is present as expected by the caller of that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @StaxMan this issue was fixed by adding the following configuration in plugin-security.policy file location on `C:\elasticsearch-2.4.1\modules\lang-groovy`:

```
permission org.elasticsearch.script.ClassPermission "java.lang.*";
permission org.elasticsearch.script.ClassPermission "java.text.*";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does sound like an incompatibility between Jackson version that one of Spring modules was compiled against (and expected to use with), and 2.8.
It may be necessary to try a more recent version of Spring (MVC?).

Note that you also will want to use Jackson 2.8.3 instead of 2.8.1, due to various bug fixes, although it probably does not matter wrt this particular issue.

Comment: thanks @StaxMan this issue was fixed added the following configuration in plugin-security.policy file location on C:\elasticsearch-2.4.1\modules\lang-groovy:

permission org.elasticsearch.script.ClassPermission "java.lang."; permission org.elasticsearch.script.ClassPermission "java.text.";